# find a string in a div and replace it with a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a

```
<h3 class="recomendedProduct">Protect</h3>
```

I want to reprace Protect with Prime. I cant change how it is reaching the dom so i have to replace it through jquery

Any suggestions? I have seen bunch of solutions but cant seem to make up my mind how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.recomendedProduct').text('Prime');
```

or

```
$('.recomendedProduct').html('Prime');
```

if your string contains HTML

([api](http://api.jquery.com/text/))

Answer (score 1):

Your title and questions don't quite add up. But if I understand your question, you want to replace one specific instance. In that case:

```
$("h3.recomendedProduct").html('Prime');
```

Comment: yeah..this was a bad question..i couldnt think streight..had to get a solution very fast... the clients were on top my head so I just asked..not a very good practice